# Oughtn't option premiums increase by the same amount as strike prices?

Tags: option-pricing

1. Pls see this question's title. In the screenshot below, as the strike prices below increase by  +1, oughtn't the option premiums increase by +1 too?
2. Why buy the \$104 put  for \$13.71? The \$105 put looks more attractive to me; it has lower IV and costs only 4 cents more!

[image]

Comment: Get on the phone to the CBOE and try to trade at the "last" price, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These quotes may not be synchronised. Also if the probability of being below either strike is zero, then why would the price change, both options will be worth zero ? Just an extreme example that shows why not. The sensitivity of the price wrt strike is $N(d_0)e^{-rT}<1$.